# Conditional execution based on the Gnuplot version

Tags: gnuplot

Since Gnuplot 4 and Gnuplot 5 are partially incompatible, I'd like to have conditional execution based on the Gnuplot version, e.g. to set some linewidth with Gnuplot 4 and some other linewidth with Gnuplot 5. How can I do this entirely in a Gnuplot script (i.e. without having to use a shell script wrapper)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable GPVAL_VERSION is always set to the version number. You can use it like any other variable. Note that it's a number, not a string. To see the other gnuplot-defined variables, type the command "show var all".

Comment: Then the OP can use `if` clauses to switch between versions, *noting that if the version is very old `if` clauses work differently or not a all*. A simple example: `if (GPVAL_VERSION == 4.6) {print "Version is 4.6"} else {if (GPVAL_VERSION == 5.0) {print "Version is 5.0"}}`.

Comment: Thanks. So, I can also use it in the ternary operator, such as: `mylw = GPVAL_VERSION < 5 ? 2 : 1`